# Output list of items with baconjs

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

Can you suggest a better way to render list of items on my page with baconjs. I need opportunity to add/delete/change elements inside this list. 
List of items should be a property, modified by events? Or something other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bacon.update (https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-update) can be used to update the list based on multiple source events like add/update/delete. You might want to try something like this:

```
var itemsP = Bacon.update(
    [],
    addE, (items, newItem) => items.concat(newItem),
    removeE, (items, removedItem) => items = items.filter((i) => i != removedItem)
);
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/1w2brL1e/1/

Comment: Looks good, but Bacon.update don't invoke callback function
https://jsfiddle.net/0rkg43rt/

Comment: Added demonstration fiddle above, based on yours, yurisnk. You had 2 issues there: 1) the function supplied to B.update didn't return the value 2) itemsP wasn't subscribed to, so it wasn't activated.